# Can't access ViewBag object inside object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have to loop from ViewBag and need to access MainCategory under its child category List. Your can get idea from Controller. But I am having problem accessing my child category item. The error says user unhanded. Please see picture bellow to get more clear idea. Any question welcome.

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            using (var ctx = new db_zikanalyticsEntities())
                {
                    var vmCats = new List<CategriesViewModel>();

                    var l1cats = ctx.Level1Cats.ToList();
                    var l2cats = ctx.Level2Cats.ToList();
                    foreach (var l1 in l1cats)
                    {
                        var catObj = new CategriesViewModel { Level1CatsName = l1.Name };
                        foreach (var l2 in l2cats)
                        {
                            if (l1.Level1CatId == l2.Level1CatId)
                            {
                                catObj.Level2CatsList.Add(new Level2Cats
                                {
                                    Level2CatId = l2.Name,
                                    Name = l2.Name,
                                    Level1CatId = l2.Level1CatId,
                                    Updated = l2.Updated
                                });
                            }
                        }
                        vmCats.Add(catObj);
                    }
                    ViewBag.MainCategory = vmCats;


                return View();
        }


    }
```

View:

```
 @foreach (var item in ViewBag.MainCategory)
                            {
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <div class="mainCategory">
                                        <h4><u>
                                            <b>@item.Level1CatsName</b>
                                            </u></h4>
                                        <h4>
                                            <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                            <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                            <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                            <i class="fa fa-star-half-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                            <i class="fa fa-star-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                        </h4>

                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-lg-1">
                                                <ul>
                                                    @foreach (var item2 in ViewBag.MainCategory.Level2CatsList)
                                                    {

                                                     <li>@item2.Name</li>


                                                    }
                                                </ul>

                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            }
```

[image: Picture1]
[image: Picture2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seeme to be the problem:

```
@foreach (var item2 in ViewBag.MainCategory.Level2CatsList)
```

For this to be the right code Level2CatsList would need to be a static member of your MainCategory class. Do all MainCategory instances have the same value for Level2CatsList?

It is likely you mean:

```
@foreach (var item2 in item.Level2CatsList)
```

the above is correct if Level2CatsList an instance member.

you may want to include the class def for MainCategory.